# Join two large datasets in R using both exact and fuzzy matching

Tags: r, join, inner-join, fuzzyjoin

I'm trying to inner join two datasets: `df1` of 50,000 obs looks something like this:

```
  Name              | Line.1           | Line.2     | Town       | County       | Postcode 
 -------------------|------------------|------------|------------|--------------|---------- 
  ACME Inc          | 63 Long Street   |            | Fakeington | Lincolnshire | PA4 8QU  
  BETA LTD          | 91a              | Main Drove | Cloud City | Something    | BN1 6LD  
  The Giga          | 344 Lorem Street |            | Ipsom      | Dolor        | G2 8LY
```

`df2` of 500,000 obs looks like this:

```
  Name              | AddressLine1   | AddressLine2     | AddressLine3 | AddressLine4 | Postcode | RatingValue 
 -------------------|----------------|------------------|--------------|--------------|----------|------------- 
  ACME              |                | 63 Long Street   | Fakeington   | Lincolnshire | PA4 8QU  | 1           
  Random Company    |                | Rose Ave         | Fakeington   |              | AB2 51GL | 5           
  BETA Limited      | Business House | 91a Main Drove   | Something    |              | BN1 6LD  | 3           
  Giga Incorporated |                | 344 Lorem Street | Ipsum        | Dolor        | G2 8LY   | 5
```

And I want to get to something like `df_final`.

```
  Name              | Postcode | RatingValue 
 -------------------|----------|------------- 
  ACME Inc          | PA4 8QU  | 1           
  BETA LTD          | BN1 6LD  | 3           
  Giga Incorporated | G2 8LY   | 5
```

These are one-to-one matches and all the values in `df1` should exist in `df2`. `Postcode` is an exact match while the address is split into multiple lines with no regular pattern, so I think my best bet is to match by `Name`.

I tried the `fuzzyjoin` package but I'm getting an `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 120.6 Gb` so I guess I have to use another method that works with bigger datasets.

Any ideas about what the best way to approach this is?

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Name = c("ACME Inc", "BETA LTD", "Giga Incorporated"),
            Line.1 = c("63 Long Street", "91a", "344 Lorem Street"),
            Line.2 = c(NA, "Main Drove", NA),
              Town = c("Fakeington", "Cloud City", "Ipsom"),
            County = c("Lincolnshire", "Something", "Dolor"),
          Postcode = c("PA4 8QU", "BN1 6LD", "G2 8LY")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Name = c("ACME", "Random Company","BETA Limited","Giga Incorporated"),
      AddressLine1 = c(NA, NA, "Business House", NA),
      AddressLine2 = c("63 Long Street", "Rose Ave","91a Main Drove","344 Lorem Street"),
      AddressLine3 = c("Fakeington", "Fakeington", "Something", "Ipsum"),
      AddressLine4 = c("Lincolnshire", NA, NA, "Dolor"),
          Postcode = c("PA4 8QU", "AB2 51GL", "BN1 6LD", "G2 8LY"),
       RatingValue = c(1L, 5L, 3L, 5L)
)
```

Comment: I would first break this down into a smaller problem. Make a dataframe from two existing columns: df1$Name and df2$Name, where the rows represent every combination of "matching" company names based on meeting some matching threshold value (soundex, string distance, whatever you want). Do a Cartesian join of df1 and df2, then filter such that you only keep only valid combinations.

Comment: @BillO'Brien A Cartesian join? `df1` is 50K rows and `df2` 500K, `50000*500000` is `2.5e+10`.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like the following will do what the question asks for. It uses package `stringdist`, not `fuzzyjoin`.

First, `merge` by `Postcode` only, since the matches are exact. Then get similarities between `Name`'s. If they are above a predetermined threshold, keep those rows.

```
thresh <- 0.75

df_final <- merge(df2[c(1, 6:7)], df1[c(1, 6)], by = "Postcode", suffixes = c("",".y"))
i <- apply(df_final[c(2, 4)], 1, function(x) {stringdist::stringsim(x[1], x[2], method = 'jw')}) >= thresh

df_final <- df_final[i, c(2, 1, 3)]

df_final 
#               Name Postcode RatingValue
#1      BETA Limited  BN1 6LD           3
#2 Giga Incorporated   G2 8LY           5
#3              ACME  PA4 8QU           1
```

Comment: That seems to have done it. I'll do a bit of cleaning to remove stopwords and adjust the threshold and test different methods, but so far so good!